# hamburger toggle button not working react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";


const Navbar = () => {

    const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
    const toggle = () => setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
    const ref = useRef()
    useEffect(() => {
        const checkIfClickedOutside = e => {
          if (isMenuOpen && ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
            setIsMenuOpen(false)
          }
        }
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside)
        return () => {
          document.removeEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside)
        }
      }, [isMenuOpen])

    return (
        <>
            <header>

                <nav>
                    <div className="nav">

                        <div className="nav-brand">
                            <Link to="./" className="text-black">Website</Link>
                        </div>
                        <div className="toggle-icon" onClick={toggle}>
                            <i id="toggle-button" className={isMenuOpen ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
                        </div>
                        {isMenuOpen && (
                            <div className={isMenuOpen ? "nav-menu visible" : "nav-menu"} ref={ref}>
                                <ul className="main-menu">

                                    <li><Link to="./" onClick={toggle}>Home</Link></li>
                                    <li><Link to="./blog" onClick={toggle}>Blog</Link></li>
                                    <li className="drp">
                                        <p className="dropbtn">Find <i className="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></p>
                                        <ul className="dropdown-content">
                                            <li><Link to="./find/portable-keyboards" onClick={toggle}>Portable Keyboards</Link></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="drp">
                                        <p className="dropbtn">More <i className="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></p>
                                        <ul className="dropdown-content">
                                            <li><Link to="./piano-notes" onClick={toggle}>Piano Notes</Link></li>
                                            <li><Link to="./chords" onClick={toggle}>Chords</Link></li>
                                            <li><Link to="./tools/metronome" onClick={toggle}>Metronome</Link></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </nav>  
            </header>

        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Everything is working fine except the toggle button. The menu is not closing after opening it. The onClick={toggle} function is not working on the close icon. The menu will hide when someone clicks outside the menu component which is working fine. I tried a lot but didn't find any method to resolve it. Can someone try to solve this issue?

Comment: Your menu button is outside the ref, so when you click the menu, you are triggering the toggle in the onClick, and then again in the mousedown event. So it is closing and opening immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The menu toggle button is *outside* the element you are attaching the outside click listener to, so when you are trying to close the menu the `toggle` callback ***and*** the `checkIfClickedOutside` handlers are cycling the `isMenuOpen` state.

## Solution

Wrap both the menu button ***and*** the menu in a div for the ref to be attached to. There is also no reason really to check if `isMenuOpen` is true in the `checkIfClickedOutside` handler. If `isMenuOpen` is already false, enqueueing another state update to set it false is generally ignored by React. This allows you to remove it as a dependency.

Example:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkIfClickedOutside = (e) => {
      if (!ref.current?.contains(e.target)) {
        setIsMenuOpen(false);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
    };

  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <nav>
          <div className="nav">
            <div className="nav-brand">
              <Link to="./" className="text-black">
                Website
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div ref={ref}> // <-- ref to this containing div
              <div className="toggle-icon" onClick={toggle}>
                <i
                  id="toggle-button"
                  className={isMenuOpen ? "fas fa-times" : "fas fa-bars"}
                />
              </div>
              {isMenuOpen && (
                <div className={isMenuOpen ? "nav-menu visible" : "nav-menu"}>
                  ....
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit hamburger-toogle-button-not-working-react]

Comment: But I am getting state= false on desktop size when there is no toggle option as it is false initially. Because of this, no menus are showing. I want this functionality only when the website is opened on mobile, not on desktop.

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA OK, this sort of seems like an extra-curricular issue to the menu toggling. It's difficult to help currently as the code you've shared doesn't appear to make any discrimination between "mobile" and "desktop". I suggest asking a new question on SO that is specific to this issue. You'll not only get more eyes on the post more quickly, but it'll be more on-topic than "tacking it on" here. Feel free to ping (@ me) here with a link to it and I can take a look.